# Android GoogleMap: how to move a marker and the camera synchronously?

Tags: android, google-maps, camera, marker

I have a problem when moving a marker on GoogleMap and the camera at the same time.

I have a marker on the map, normally it is located at the center of the map if user does not scroll the map. The marker represents the current position, which is provided by an external source.

When the position changes, I want to move the marker to the new location, and at the same time move the camera along with it, so it is always centered at the map (the effect looks like that only the map moves).

I'm doing this by some code like the following,

```
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(rawData.latitude, rawData.longitude);
mMarker.setPosition(latlng);  // move the marker

CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, mCurrZoom);
mMap.moveCamera(update);  // move the camera
```

However, there's some flickering sometimes. It looks like the map and the marker are rendered in different threads, so sometimes the marker is moved before the camera and sometimes vice versa. If the marker is moved first, it will be drawn in a place which is not in the center anymore, and then shortly after the camera moves, the marker will be drawn again at the center, thus causes a flickering.

How to make the marker and the camera be moved synchronously?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(yourLatitude, yourLongitude), zommvalue));
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. This avoids flickering but introduces the animation which is not preferred. I want to keep the marker static unless user scrolls or zooms the map.

I tried using an ImageView to replace the marker, and update the image view's position when needed. However, it is very laggy when scrolling the map.

Anyway, I will use the animation to avoid the flickering unless I find a better solution.